# Subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^k$ of finite index $n$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I want to describe all subgroups  in $\mathbb{Z}^k$ of finite index $n$.
I have solved it for the case $k=2$. In $\mathbb{Z}^2$, each subgroup of index $n$ corresponds to a matrix $\left( \begin{array}{a}
a & b \\
0 & d \end{array} \right)$ with $a, b, d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $ad=n; a,d>0; 0 \le b<d$. Can someone give a hint how to go about it in the general case? For the case $k=3$, my guess is that each subgroup corresponds to a matrix $\left( \begin{array}{a}
a & b & c \\
0 & d & e \\
0 & 0 & f \end{array} \right)$ where $a, b, c, d, e, f \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $adf=n$; a, d, f >0; $0 \le b <d; 0 \le c <f; 0 \le e<f$. Is this right?

Comment: I think I am not getting something - how are you viewing $\mathbb{Z}^n$ as matrices?

Comment: Also, my personal approach would be to think about how $\mathbb{Z}^n$ can map onto some abelian group $A$ of order $m$. This gives a number of subgroups of index $m$. Do this for all abelian groups of order $m$. For example, if $\langle a, b; [a, b]\rangle\rightarrow K_4$ the Klein $4$-group then $a$ and $b$ must both have order two. This gives you a unique kernel, $N=\langle a^2, b^2\rangle$.

Comment: He's viewing $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and its subgroups as matrices using, I think, the theory discussed in Artin's book or more generally in Dummit and Foote's book.

Comment: @DerekAllums: I have neither of these books! I presume the operation has to be addition, as if $a$ and $d$ have absolute value other than $1$ then the matrices are not invertible (in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$), but then this looks like $\mathbb{Z}^3$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}^2$...

Comment: @user1729 The idea is to keep track of the relations: the columns correspond to generators and the rows give the relations among them.

Answer (score 5):

If $\Gamma<\Bbb Z^k$ has index $n$, then $n(\Bbb Z^k/\Gamma)=(0)$. Therefore $\Gamma$ contains the subgroup $(n\Bbb Z)^k$.

This shows that there's a bijection between the wanted subgroups and the subgroups of
$$\Bbb Z^k/(n\Bbb Z)^k\simeq(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^k$$
of index $n$.

Then one can simply apply the structure theorem for finite abelian groups.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{Z}^k/(n\mathbb{Z})^k$?

Comment: The quotient of $\Bbb Z^k$ by its subgroup $(n\Bbb Z)^k$

Comment: Ah, it is obvious now!

Comment: I think for general $n$ (and in particular for prime powers), "simply" is a bit optimistic (though it certainly _can_ be done). Would you know how many subgroups of order $p^{(k-1)l}$ there are in $(\Bbb Z/p^l\Bbb Z)^k$?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen : By duality, this is the same as the number of subgroups of order $p^l$ and this is maybe easier. (Is it?) I agree that the combinatorics tend to explode, but it is quite clear what is going on.

Comment: This subject has been studied extensively (I'm reading an article about it right now), and though there is nothing mysterious about it, details are surprisingly complicated. I think the answer involves a sum over the partitions of $l$ (for the types the subgroup can have) and each summand is a product of powers of $p$ and of Gaussian binomial coefficients evaluated at $p$ (usually written in the form $\binom nm_p$). Somewhat hairy stuff.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Would you please give a link of the article?

Comment: @Shiva: What I am reading is Lynne M. Butler: Memoirs of the Am. Math. Soc. 539 (1994) "Subgroup Lattices and Symmetric Functions". There is also a chapter (II) of the well known book "Symmetric functions and Hall polynomials" by I.G. Macdonald (in fact the part about Hall polynomials) dedicated to this (the approach of Butler is a bit different; the book may be the best access to the work of Philip Hall and J.A. Green (1961 lecture notes, probably hard to get) on this subject).